# Resizing chart.js chart using Bootstrap/Vue

Tags: bootstrap-4, chart.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-chartjs

My page has two Bootstrap rows and 2 columns within the row. I want to force each row to take up exactly half of the page. I was able to achieve this using the Bootstrap sizing classes initially (using the h-50 class for each of the rows). However, once I add in my chart.js chart into one of the columns, the row that it's in automatically expands to fill up the entire height of the page, breaking the visual appearance. (It still follows the width of the column, and takes up half the width of the page.)

The chart is responsive when I resize the page, however, it simply is not responsive to the size of its container (the column within the row).

Where/what should I add in to make the chart responsive to the size of its container? Thank you!

My code on the page where the chart is displayed is as follows:

```
    <div class="border border-info" style="height:95%">
        <div class="row border border-primary h-50">
            <div class="col border border-danger w-50" >
                <DayChart></DayChart>
            </div>
            <div class="col border border-success w-50">
                today
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row border border-warning h-50">
            <div class="col border border-primary">
                zach put ur d3 here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My code on the page where I initialised the chart is as follows:

```
<template>
    <Doughnut
      :chart-options="chartOptions"
      :chart-data="chartData"
      :chart-id="chartId"
      :dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
      :plugins="plugins"
      :css-classes="cssClasses"
      :styles="styles"
      :width="width"
      :height="height"
    />
  </template>

<script>
    import { defineComponent, h } from 'vue';
    
    import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs';
    
    import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js';
    
    ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale);
    
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'DayChart',
        components: {
            Doughnut
        },
        props: {
            chartId: {
                type: String,
                default: 'doughnut-chart'
            },
            datasetIdKey: {
                type: String,
                default: 'label'
            },
            width: {
                type: Number,
                default: 100,
            },
            height: {
                type: Number,
                default: 100,
            },
            cssClasses: {
                default: '',
                type: String
            },
            styles: {
                default: {}
            },
            plugins: {
                default: []
            },
            chartData: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => ({
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ]
                            }]
            })
            }
        },
        setup(props) {
            return () =>
                h(Doughnut, {
                    chartData: props.chartData,
                    chartOptions: props.chartOptions,
                    chartId: props.chartId,
                    width: props.width,
                    height: props.height,
                    cssClasses: props.cssClasses,
                    styles: props.styles,
                    plugins: props.plugins
                });
        }
    });
    </script>
```